# Fibaro requesting prices Lua 5.1

Tags: lua

Luarocks wont work on fibaro, so im removing this

Comment: Looks like your Lua environment is sandboxed and intentionally does not allow `require` (and other potentially dangerous functions)

Answer (score 1):

As Egor suggested, Fibaro sandboxes their Lua environment. A full list of what is removed is listed at https://manuals.fibaro.com/knowledge-base-browse/blocked-lua-commands/, but it includes `require`, `dofile`, `load`, `loadfile`, `loadstring`, several functions in the `os` library, and the entire `io` and `package` library.

That effectively requires all of your code to be contained in a single file, with no access to modules, packages, or libraries other than the remaining parts of the standard library, which means you simply can't do what you're trying to do here.